# Sonarcloud failure with Travis, Maven & github

Tags: java, maven, github, sonarqube, travis-ci

A project I work on ([eclipse/scanning](https://github.com/eclipse/scanning)) uses Travis and Sonar for continuous integration and code analysis.

Last week, I noticed that builds were failing at the sonar step with:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
```

After some research, I thought I'd [fixed this](https://github.com/eclipse/scanning/pull/183) by updating the `addons:` section (`sonarqube` to `sonarcloud`) and switching to using `- mvn -q sonar:sonar` rather than `- sonar-scanner` in the `script:` section of the `.travis.yml` file.

Now though, external pull requests (from forks) which make it past the integration tests are failing for a different reason at the sonar step:

```
$ mvn -q sonar:sonar
...
[ERROR] SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project org.eclipse.scanning: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
```

This appears to be related to earlier differences in the log:

```
Encrypted environment variables have been removed for security reasons.
See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests/#Pull-Requests-and-Security-Restrictions
```

and an entirely missing *SonarCloud addon* section.

To see the difference, compare the [failed build #625](https://travis-ci.org/eclipse/scanning/builds/262316508) (which was a pull request from a forked repo) with the [successful build #628](https://travis-ci.org/eclipse/scanning/builds/262347065) (which was a pull request from within the repo).

Around a month ago, external pulls work without issue, for instance [build #536](https://travis-ci.org/eclipse/scanning/builds/252379252) passed, having run `Setting environment variables from repository settings`, `SonarCloud addon` and `sonar-scanner` correctly.

Subsequent builds however, such as [build #538](https://travis-ci.org/eclipse/scanning/builds/252504791) passed, but only because `sonar-scanner` skipped analysis and `exited with 0` even though they failed to run.

While I could probably just disable Sonar on external pull requests, it would be nice if I could fix our repository so we got both integration tests and code analysis on both internal and external pull requests, so

- Was my original fix the correct one?

  - If so, how do I get it to work with both internal and external pull requests?
  - If not, how should I have fixed the original problem?

---

Note, this question has been superceded by [How do I get Sonarcloud to run on pull requests from forks with Travis, Maven & github](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45612758/42473) which is focussed on the underlying problem rather than trying to fix some of the symptoms.

Answer (score 8):

Your PR analysis is attempting (and failing) to use the default server: localhost:9000.

In another circumstance, you would [update *settings.xml*](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-GlobalSettings) to specify the location but since you're using Travis, you'll pass it on the command line instead: `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io`

BTW, this is working in your normal Travis build because the SonarQube integration for Travis is specifically a Travis-*SonarCloud* integration, so server is filled in automatically.

Comment: Thanks, any thoughts on what that URL might need to be? We haven't needed this before, and some Travis jobs run fine without it, for instance https://travis-ci.org/eclipse/scanning/jobs/262286564 worked fine without a `-Dsonar.host.url` (presumably to the `mvn sonar:sonar` command?). I'll update my question tomorrow morning after all of our queued travis jobs run (we have failed to get Travis to take our money for higher priority, so things get slow after 3pm BST).

Comment: See my updated answer @MarkBooth

Comment: Thanks again. When I add this the `mvn Sonar:Sonar` error changes to `Insufficient privileges`, which confirms that this is a problem with the earlier `Encrypted environment variables have been removed for security reasons.` error, see https://travis-ci.org/eclipse/scanning/builds/262997253 I think I need to be asking ask a different question - "How do I get Sonar to run on pull requests from forks". I'll link back here when I do.

Answer (score -2):

you can try to delete the `directory data/es` of your Sonar Qube. then restart yoyr SonarQube, SonarQube will be recreate all the ES indexe.

Comment: Thanks Mayank Sharma, but as far as I know, a clean/empty docker container is created for each travis build. It is certainly clean enough that it has to clone all of the repos as part of the build process.