# Sonar `should be relative to project baseDir` error in travis

Tags: eclipse, maven, github, sonarqube, travis-ci

Some time between the [11th September](https://travis-ci.org/eclipse/scanning/builds/275387966) and the [14th September](https://travis-ci.org/eclipse/scanning/builds/274095160), running sonar through our travis build started failing with an `org.eclipse.dawnsci.targetplatform should be relative to project baseDir` error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project org.eclipse.scanning: Dir /home/travis/build/eclipse/org.eclipse.dawnsci/org.eclipse.dawnsci.targetplatform should be relative to project baseDir -> [Help 1]
```

Looking through the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/scanning/blob/master/pom.xml) the `org.eclipse.dawnsci` module does stand out as being different to all of the others:

```
  <modules>
    <module>org.eclipse.scanning.target.platform</module>
    <module>../org.eclipse.dawnsci</module>
    <module>org.eclipse.scanning.api</module>
    ...
  </modules>
```

I have tried updating [`sonar-project.properties`](https://github.com/eclipse/scanning/blob/master/sonar-project.properties) from

```
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,**/*.class
```

to each of the following:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,**/*.class,../org.eclipse.dawnsci
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,**/*.class,org.eclipse.dawnsci*
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,**/*.class,org.eclipse.dawnsci**
```

but none of these changes helped.

After [previous problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45612758/42473) I have added `--fail-never` to the `mvn -q sonar:sonar` command in [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/eclipse/scanning/blob/master/.travis.yml) so this problem won't prevent pull requests being merged, but it would be nice to have sonar reports on our repo again.

Any suggestions about how I can fix our travis build would be appreciated?

Comment: We are aware of the problem, and I'm investigating. I'll post an answer when I find the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We changed the way we validate project layout, and it leads to this error. A [ticket was created](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9835) to track this change, and we are currently discussing options (like updating the SonarQube Scanner for Maven). Feel free to follow it for updates, and sorry for the inconvenience.

For your specific case, one workaround is to create a build profile, and exclude module `../org.eclipse.dawnsci` when running the SonarCloud analysis. Or move the module to be under the project basedir (and avoid using `..` in module location).

As a side note, there is no point maintaining the file `sonar-project.properties` if you are using the Scanner for Maven (`mvn sonar:sonar`) since the Scanner for Maven will only read configuration from pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, `dawnsci` is an external project, so I don't think it can be moved. I switched to using `mvn` when the old `sonarqube` config stopped working (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45573102/42473)). The person who set this all up left, and no-one here knows how this works, so I'm rather flailing in the dark. I'm [trying out the build module option now](https://travis-ci.org/eclipse/scanning/builds/277222909).

Comment: If dawnsci is an external project then you should probably not analyze it in SonarCloud as part of your project, since its technical debt is not under your control.

Comment: Agreed, I think `dawnsci` only started to be analysed when I switched to running sonar through `mvn` rather than using `sonar-scanner`. `dawnsci` wasn't in the `sonar.inclusions` listed in the `sonar-project.properties`, but is in the `<modules>` list in the `pom.xml` as it is needed to build and run the tests.

Comment: Incidentally, the build profile did seem to fix this. Sadly we are having problems with travis taking 5+ hours to run jobs at the moment, which is making it difficult to test.

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by Julien H. - SonarSource Team](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46279014/42473) adding a profile did solve this problem.

In the `pom.xml` I changed

```
<modules>
    <module>org.eclipse.scanning.target.platform</module>
    <module>../org.eclipse.dawnsci</module>
    ...
</modules>
```

to

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>externalModules</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
        <modules>
            <module>../org.eclipse.dawnsci</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<modules>
    <module>org.eclipse.scanning.target.platform</module>
    ...
</modules>
```

so that the module is included by default.

I then added `-P !externalModules` to my `mvn sonar:sonar` command in `.travis.yml` so that it was excluded when running sonar analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over the same problem and finally came to the conclusion that this has all been fixed in the latest sonar-maven-plugin 3.4. You can simply upgrade your dependency to this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.905</version>
</plugin>
```